# Why my Texture Paint is always Symmetric and how to disable mirror?

Tags: texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

I create a simple model with mirror by Y-axis

Then I apply this mirror in the modifier properties
I paint this model in Texture Paint and it always mirror by Y-axis, even the mirror is disable.

How can I do to disable this mirror?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you re-do your UV's after applying the mirror modifier? If not, both halves of the model will use the same(flipped) UV island, hence the mirrored texture.

Comment: Thank you @oaaya, I redo the UV and it works ok now. <3

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and find this solution which helped me:

https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/tjzs7y/cant_texture_paint_without_it_mirroring_which_i/i1ncna2/?context=8&depth=9

Essentially, after using the mirror modifier you need to unwrap your mesh.
You do so by going to Layout, Edit Mode, press "a" to select the entire mesh then press "u" and select "Smart UV Project". After doing so you can go back to Texture Paint and the mirror won't be an issue anymore